# Approve that if there is a lower bound for each $A \subseteq R $ then there is $infA$

Tags: calculus

I must approve that if there is a lower bound for each $ A\subseteq R $ then there is $infA$. ($A \neq \emptyset$)

I'm sure that there is a related post for this but I would like to validate my solution to better understand the topic of $sup$ and $inf$.

*My solution:*

Let us define a set A which is not empty set and there is a lower bound. Let us also define a set B such that

$B = \{ x \in R : x$ is lower bound of A $\}$

$B$ is not empty because there is a $m \leqslant x $ for all $x\in A$.

Is $infA =m $?

Two cases:

1. Let us consider that $ m \neq infA$ then $\exists e > 0$ such that
   $\forall x \in A$, $m+e \leqslant x$.

   So, $m+e \in B$ and $m+e>m$.

   We wonder if there is $supB$. If there is $supB$ then $supB = infA$

   Let us assume that there isn't $supB$. Then there is $e > 0$ for
   each $x>0$ so that

   $x \leqslant M - e$ where $ x \leqslant M $ for each $x \in B$

   Let us define $M = m + e $, then $x \leqslant m$, which is
   impossible because

   $m+e >m$.  Consequently, $ x > M -e $.

   As a result, $supB=M=infA$
2. If $infA=m$ then there is $infA$

From (1) and (2), there is always $infA$

Could you validate my solution ?

**EDIT:**

1. Can we assume that $supB = infA$ ?
2. Can we select the $M = m + e$ ?
3. Introducing the above two cases, can we assume that there is always $infA$ ?

Comment: Actually, $B$ might be empty. You should use $x \in \mathbb{R}$ instead.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I will edit it.